# Binary files/folders version control in 2020?

Tags: version-control, backup, versioning

I'd like to keep a "snapshots/versions" of a folder containing lots of huge binary files. The folder contains all my backups made via `rsync/rclone/scp/whatever`.
Since the source can be corrupted/hacked whatever, I'd like to keep all the versions.

We all know git/subversion aren't made for files other than text and I wonder if there is a more general tool for that purpose.

I'll exclusively use linux.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### [git-annex](https://git-annex.branchable.com/) is definitely the tool you want for this job.

Great docs, amazing code, awesome community.

Quick start guide:

Install it with `sudo apt-get install git-annex` then it's on to managing your data just like you'd do with git.

```sh
git init
git annex init "main-backup"
git annex add  # if you don't specify any paths, it adds everything
# it'll hash your files and store them inside the .git folder with their hash as their filenames
git commit -m "Add my most important files"
```

Comment: Never heard of it despite all the searchs I've made. It takes forever to add all files `git annex add`, it seems it's copying the files somewhere?!

Comment: Also git-annex replaces all the files by symlinks. That breaks the workflow using rclone and rsync.

Comment: git-annex doesn't copy the files unless you tell it to. It does hash the files with SHA256 by default. And hashing requires lots of I/O. The symlinks are there for your safety. And I'm positive there are ways to get rsync to follow the symlinks on the destination. You could also create a git-annex repo on the source and instead of rsync-ing between source and destination, you could just `git annex sync`.

Comment: Reading your question again made me think [bup](https://github.com/bup/bup) could be useful, because it uses a rolling-checksum to split large files into chunks and deduplicate amongst those. Btw, git-annex also supports bup as a remote, so you could enjoy deduplication with the friendly git-annex interface.

Comment: With `rclone -S` to follow symlinks, it can't sync. I get ` [..] permission denied` because all the files in `.git/annex/objects/...` are read-only. I'll try with `bup`.

Comment: I just remembered there's an option that enables git-annex to use hard-links instead of symlinks. Maybe that would work? See at the end of the page: [annex.thin](https://git-annex.branchable.com/tips/unlocked_files/)

Comment: I didn't read that part, that should since it should remove the read-only. From what I understood, using unlocked files doesn't give the possibility to checkout a previous version. A single (or 2 max) version of the file is stored. Am I wrong? I'll try and let you know.

Comment: When you `git annex unlock` a file in a normal repo, it makes a copy of it. So you'd store two versions of the same file. One editable, one normal. However, on a `annex.thin` repo, it only hardlinks to the file inside `.git/annex/objects`. So, yeah, if you modify it without any other copies, the old file will be lost forever.